# MySQL cursor: unknown column "done" in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, cursor

I'm trying to use a cursor loop in MYSQL, but it's not working. I've essentially copied the example from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html, except I use a function instead of a procedure. Does that matter?

When I try to run the function - select xxx() from dual - I get an error: unknown column "done" in 'field list'. What to do?

```
delimiter $$
create function xxx()
returns int deterministic
    begin
        DECLARE a INT;
        DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id  FROM my_table;

        OPEN cur1;

        read_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur1 INTO a;
            IF done THEN
              LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE cur1;   
      return 1;     
end$$
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didnt declared `done`. 
`DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;`
and at the end
 `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;`

Comment: That did it, thanks. And it was right there in the example, too.